# Jinja SandboxedEnvironment and Zope2 Restricted Python

Tags: python, zope, zpt, jinja2

Jinja's [sandbox](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/sandbox/) and the Zope 2 RestrictedPython seem to solve similar problems. Is there a way to layer them, i.e. use RestrictedPython policies in a Jinja environment? The use case is retrofitting Jinja templates to an existing Zope2-based product, to replace ZPT / TAL.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. Jinja's and Zope's implementations are highly different, and not interoperable.